# Understanding Endpoints?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

new to App Engine, but I've built a basic API on GCE that takes an integer and adds 1 to it and deployed it to the Cloud Endpoints API Explorer. I've tested it in my browser and can confirm it works.

My problem is implementing it inside of my MainActivity. The API file is built inside my "endpoints module", which keeps it from being accessed inside the app module

[image]

Does anyone understand what I'm doing wrong? I can also show some code if it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the "endpoints-backend" module been added as a dependancy to the "app" module?

1. Right click App module
2. Open module settings
3. Dependancies tab
4. If "endpoints-backend" isn't list click the + bottom left
5. Module dependancy
6. Select "endpoints-backend"
7. Sync project with gradle files

Comment: Amazing how simple that was. Thanks!